# How to post jwt token along with a request via nodejs using aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, jwt

I have the following code which hits the remote API properly and returning result as expected.

```
const http = require('http');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let dataString = '';
    
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = http.get("url", function(res) {
          res.on('data', chunk => {
            dataString += chunk;
          });
          res.on('end', () => {
            resolve({
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(dataString), null, 4)
            });
          });
        });
        
        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject({
              statusCode: 500,
              body: 'Something went wrong!'
          });
        });
    });
    
    return response;
};
```

But i have to use a jwt token to hit this api properly. How can i do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the JWT token using the `Authorization` header:

```js
const http = require('http');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let dataString = '';
    const token = "...." // <- your JWT token
    
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
        }
        const req = http.get("url", options, function(res) { [...] }
    });
    
    return response;
};
```

**Please** do not hardcode the token in your production code. Either pass it in the event, set it in the environment variables, load it from SSM or use AppConfig.